# Django Allauth Error: "'socialaccount' is not a registered tag library"

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm following the instructions for using **django-allauth** as shown [here](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html). I'm not interested in using social authentication - just a simple email and password signup flow.  For some reason, when I go to `/accounts/login/` I get the error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /accounts/login/
'socialaccount' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
account
account_tags
...
```

[image]

In my `settings.py` I have

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


# Required by allauth
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)


# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps
    'trinalysis_app.apps.TrinalysisAppConfig',

    # Third party apps
    'django.contrib.sites', # Django app required for using allauth
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',

    # Default apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

# Set AUTH_USER_MODEL as my own user model that uses the email address as the username 
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'trinalysis_app.MyUser'


# allauth config params
SITE_ID = 1
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/1294) on github. Take a look

Comment: @vishes_shell Ahh, surprised I didn't find this in my searching.  Thanks.  I guess I should just override the default templates with my own?

Comment: I think @karthikr's answer will solve the problem too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You  need to add `allauth.socialaccount` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

More on this can be found in the [settings documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#django)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add allauth.socialaccount to INSTALLED_APPS or override login.html template and not include 'socialaccount' tag.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with same error in future.

There will be some conditions if you see such error

```
'socialaccount' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
 accounts
 account_tags
 ....
```

1. if you have imported `{% load socialaccount %}` in template. eg. login.html and not included `allauth.socialaccounts` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. or you didn't `makemigrations` or did not `migrate` . you have done makemigrations and migrated

in my case i removed all all.auth from settings.py but forget to remove `{% load socialaccount %}` from template file.. 
but solved in time ..